# How to understand "A class with only a single instance is typically just represented as a normal object in JavaScript/TypeScript."

Tags: typescript

Source: [Why No Static Classes?](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#why-no-static-classes).

I understand what other sentences mean. But this sentence, `A class with only a single instance is typically just represented as a normal object in JavaScript/TypeScript`, make me comfused.

**Does it mean singleton pattern??** What's the **`normal object`**?? I think `class` is also normal object, and its instance, too.

Comment: `class` is `function`. `function` is extends `object`

Comment: @TachibanaShin So they are all objects?

Comment: essentially everything in javascript (except undefined) is an object. however i want to mention here that if you run `typeof class {}` it will return the class type as `function`

Comment: @TachibanaShin Okay, I know these, thank you for you point out. But this didn't solve my confusion. I still don't know what this sentence means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that instead of writing a class like this:

```
class Helpers {
    static square(x: number): number {
        return x * x;
    }
    
    static cube(x: number): number {
        return x * x * x;
    }
}
```

You should just make an object:

```
const Helpers = {
    square(x: number): number {
        return x * x;
    },
    
    cube(x: number): number {
        return x * x * x;
    },
};
```

Since the class is never supposed to be instantiated, there is no need for it to be a class. In contrast, other languages like Java and C# would require you to make `Helpers` a class because everything in those languages has to be in a class.